# Reflection to find all methods with a PostSharp aspect applied

Tags: c#, reflection, postsharp

I have an `OnMethodBoundary` aspect I created to keep track of progress events in a template method. One of the things that would be useful to know in terms of the overall progress is the number of progress steps that are required by my process before it finishes, i.e. the number of methods tagged with my `[AffectsProgress]` attribute.

Rather than hard coding it and having to maintain that as I add and remove methods, I've tried using `System.Reflection` to determine that with code like the following (there were many variants I tried):

```
typeof (MyModuleWithProgressSteps)
.GetMethods(/* whatever BindingFlags I need */)
.SelectMany(x => x.CustomAttributes.Where(attribute => attribute.AttributeType == typeof (AffectsProgress)))
```

However, even though I was able to see other attributes when I removed the `Where` clause, I was unable to find any PostSharp aspects. My naive guess is that PostSharp aspects that interfere with the call stack upon execution aren't actually traditional method attributes and so the `System.Reflection` library doesn't see them.

Does anyone know of a way I could get what I'm looking for either with `System.Reflection` or with PostSharp itself? I came across [ReflectionSearch](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_reflection_reflectionsearch) and [IAspectRepositoryService](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_iaspectrepositoryservice) which require the Ultimate edition but I'm not sure if those are sufficient or not.

Edit: Resolved by @Daniel Balas. Using that answer and the information I found [here](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/multicasting-of-custom-attributes) I ended up with a custom aspect that looked like this and was able to be detected at runtime by reflection:

```
    [Serializable]
    [MulticastAttributeUsage(PersistMetaData = true)]
    internal class AffectsProgress : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
        public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            // do all my progress-related stuff here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multicast attributes are by default removed during the multicasting phase and all instances (there can be quite many if you i.e. multicast to all methods) are passed internally to the Aspect Framework.

You can tell the multicast engine not to remove metadata so that you can access the attribute at runtime. This is done like this:

```
[MulticastAttributeUsage(PersistMetaData = true)]
```

Aspect attributes will then be present on declarations on which they have been applied on (i.e. MethodLevelAspect on methods, TypeLevel aspect on types, etc.).

Comment: I'm going to try this now. This looks very promising.

Comment: Woohoo! This works exactly as advertised and addresses my needs perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Aspects get weaved as IL code by PostSharp, so the attributes that represent aspects have disappeared after PostSharp has done its post-processing.

The [ReflectionSearch](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_reflection_reflectionsearch) should help here (I never tried on my own), because it says:

> These methods are only available at build time.

And at build time, that's the last chance to access an aspect attribute before it disappears.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like adding a pre-build step for automatic code modification or using method naming conventions for reflection purposes are the only alternatives to hardcoding. Strangely, hardcoding seems like the cleanest approach here since the number of progress steps won't change too much once the process has been fully fleshed out.

Comment: @S.C. Well, I dislike hard-coding, but perhaps you can make a pre-build-step that counts the number of aspects and modifies your hard-coded value.

Comment: Very much agreed and I've done my share of automated code generation/modification, but without PostSharp Ultimate I'm left with text processing as the best way to count aspects. While that's reasonably straight forward, commented out aspects, documentation of rationale for anyone who inherits this, and other nuances along those lines would I fear make the automated counting code more risky to maintain in the long run than a constant that will rarely change. I was thinking also of a scheme within that aspect that would embed something I could find with reflection, but nothing concrete yet.

Comment: There's also the option redundant vanilla attributes just for reflection purposes I suppose. Doesn't sound like there is an elegant solution unless I move away from AOP, though.